# Should GMail Account mandatory for publishing android app in playstore?

Tags: android, google-play

So I'm going to publish my first android app in PlayStore, Can anyone help me on what is the standard industry practice on the account used while publishing the app in PlayStore?

Our organization has `abcd@organisation.com`, Can i use this email id? or should we create a Gmail account explicitly?

Comment: If you are using custiom domain email you first need to register in https://apps.google.com/ then you can use the same to login to goole and publish apps in playstore. Google app is paid service if you are fine you can use it. else you need to create a Gmail account and publish the apps

Comment: I do not think you need to open Gmail account, try to register and if they ask for Gmail account create one.
is was faster to check this

Answer (score 0):

If your organization's email is not registered with Google then you have to create a gmail account to create a developer account. Its better you create a gmail account with your Organization's name and use that email to create a playstore developer account.

Visit [this](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) link to create a developer account.

The developer account charge is $25.